# Proof of Proposition 9.7 in Krantz, "Real Analysis and Foundations," 4th edition, page 205

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The author wishes to prove the following: let $f$ and $g$ be real analytic on an open interval $I$ and assume $g$ does not vanish on $I$. Then $f/g$ is real analytic on $I$, and if $I$ is centered at $c$, then $\frac{f}{g}$ has a power series representation centered at $c$ given by formal long division.

The author notes that it suffices to prove that the series $S$ with coefficients $c_j$ centered at $c$, where $c_j$ are given by formal long division, converges on $I$, by a previous proposition. I agree with this. He then assumes that $c = 0$, which I agree we can do by a translation argument. He then says we may assume that $I$ has radius $1 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, because we can always scale the coefficients of the power series representing $f$ and $g$, which I understand. He then shows that $\{c_j\}$ is bounded, and I understand this part of the proof. He then says that this implies that $S$ has radius of convergence 1, and then promptly ends the proof. I have two issues:

1. How do we know $S$ has radius of convergence exactly 1? Isn't its radius of convergence at least 1? The argument I have in mind is that if $M$ is an upper bound for $\{c_j\}$, then

$$S \leq M\sum |x|^j$$

and the latter has radius of convergence 1, but that does not force $S$ to have radius of convergence 1 as far as I can tell.

2. More importantly, granted my first point of contention is resolved, how are we done? Aren't we to show that $S$ converges on $I$, and doesn't $I$ have radius of convergence strictly larger than 1?

Comment: the power series of $f/g$ may have a radius of convergence strictly less than the one of $f$; the important things are that the radius of convergence is non-zero and on the interval of convergence the series converges to $f/g$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We proved that for any $\varepsilon$ such that $|I|=1+\varepsilon$, the radius of convergence of $S$ is *at least* 1 (as you noted). By the freedom of choice of $\varepsilon$ we are done.

Note that if $S\subset I$, then we have $1\leq |S| \leq |I| = 1+\varepsilon$.
As $\varepsilon\to 0$, by squeeze theorem the inequalities above turn out to be equalities. So we have that $|S|=|I|$ and both intervals are cocentric. Therefore both are equal.

Comment: See, this is what I wanted to say. The author claims the radius of convergence of $S$ is exactly 1, so I was left scratching my head.